# Dynamic query with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is this possible to do sth as following:

```
public class Months
{
    public double Jan {get;set;}
    public double Feb {get;set;}
    public double Mar {get;set;}
}
```

and then

```
List<Months> myList = new List<Months>();
string monthName = "Jan";
```

and is it possbile something like this?

```
myList.where(x=>x.PropertyName.Equals(monthName))
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Every instance of the `Months` class has that property.

Comment: Yes with reflection, but why do you need it? You could switch easily that string to find the correct property or use a `Dictionary<string,double>` in the class instead.

Comment: What's the purpose of class `Months`? Maybe you wanted an `enum` instead?

Comment: A dictionary from month (as an enum, potentially) to `double` would be much cleaner, IMO.

Comment: I just gave example with 3 props, in 12 months i prefer other way then switch.

Comment: I think you'd better use enum.

Comment: Do you want to get property value by property name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note sure what is en expected value, but this would give you the value of the matching property.

```
List<Months> myList = new List<Months>();
myList.Add(new Months(){ Jan = 2.2});
string monthName = "Jan";
var result = myList.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(monthName).GetValue(x, null));
```

Comment: when I compile i have "No overload for method "GetValue" takes 1 arguemtns

Comment: try GetValue(x, null) the reason for the difference in code is that .net 4.0 GetValue takes one parameter, whereas everything below 4.0 takes two...

Answer (score 2):

Your sample looks strange. Each `Month` class has `Jan` property.

**Update:**

```
public class Months
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, double> _backfiends;

    public double Jan
    {
        get { return _backfiends["Jan"]; }
        set { _backfiends["Jan"] = value; }
    }

    public IDictionary<string, double> Backfields
    {
        get { return _backfiends; }   
    }

    public Months()
    {
        _backfiends = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        _backfiends["Jan"] = 0;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var myList = new List<Months>();
myList.Add(new Months(){Jan = 123});
var withJan = myList.Select(x => x.Backfields["Jan"]);
```

Comment: The problem is: All objects in this list are of the same type. This where condition will always return either all or none of the items in the list. Seems rather pointless.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgart, see update, I'm just guessing that he needs to select the objects having a certain property. He can simply and in list some `MonthDec` inherited from `Month` and seach `Dec`.

Comment: I don't think that's what he is asking. The sample list in his question clearly is of type `Months`.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgart example of usage: finally i will have class with properites of name 12 months, and then after user will select a date from calendar and i will get know which month he selected then i will get from my list only those properties which have name of month name selected be the user.

Comment: @kosnkov: So Adams answer most likely is what you want to do.

Comment: I guess `IDictionary<string, double>` is better to use for your purpose

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using enum for such cases, and there are lots of things you can do with enums, I bring an example :

Enum definition:

```
public enum Month 
{ Jan=1, Feb, Mar, Apr, may, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec }
```

in button click :

```
Month current = Month.Jan; //staticly checking a month

if(current == Month.Jan)
    MessageBox.Show("It's Jan");
else
    MessageBox.Show("It's not Jan.");

List<Month> specialMonthes = new List<Month>();
specialMonthes.Add(Month.Oct);
specialMonthes.Add(Month.Apr);
specialMonthes.Add(Month.Jan);
//Search the list for the month we are in now
foreach (Month specialMonth in specialMonthes)
{
    if ((int)specialMonth == DateTime.Now.Month) //dynamically checking this month
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("It's {0} now & {0} is a special month.",  
            specialMonth));
        //Output: It's Jan now and Jan is a special month.
}
```

You can intanciate, you can compare, you can cast.
So why not use enums? When you have a car you needn't run.

Comment: I disagree with the idea of using a class where we can achieve the same behaviours with an enum.